# Switch values by drag and dropping

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm just learning to do android and I was trying to do some kind of rearrange in a list of objects but I realize that I don't actually need to change their positions at all for my requirements. 
I want the drag method to just draw a shadow and when you drop it switch the text values between them and update the screen to see the changes.

Comment: You can help us better understand your problem by including what you have tried so far, preferably in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the expected output if any.

Comment: I have 4 different projects where I tried this, the simpler one is [this](http://www.pastebin.ca/3034560) I have 3 textviews inside a tablerow. In this case all 3 values switch between them if you touch anywhere, something I don't want.